# Using an other command in alias

Tags: shell, alias, zsh

When this command is run, it is not the time to submit the command, But print the `source ~/.zshrc` time.

~/.zshrc:

```
alias gitCommitAll="git add . && git commit -m \"`date +\"%T\"`\""
```

eg.

`source ~/.zshrc` at 10:00
`gitCommitAll` at 10:10 ==> `git commit -m "10:00"` not 10:10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
alias gitCommitAll='git add . && git commit -m "`date +%T`"'
```

Backquote (``) inside double quotes (`""`) will be executed prematurely. Try using single quotes (`''`) instead.

Comment: This works, but it's not nearly as widely applicable a solution as "use a function instead" (which is how the freenode #bash channel answers alias-misuse questions in general -- I'd argue rightly).

Answer (score 2):

Don't use an alias; use a function instead. It makes quoting far easier. Something like

```
gitCommitAll () {
  git add . && git commit -m "$(date +%T) $1"
}
```

How you handle the argument(s) to the function depend on what you intended the alias to do. It *looks* like you meant for all (or at least the first) "argument" to be part of the `-m` option, as a time alone isn't much of a commit message. The above just includes the first argument as part of the message.

Comment: Might switch to `commit -m "$(date +%T) $@"`. Putting it inside the quotes at the end of the string means the first argument will be appended to the string, and subsequent ones will be passed to `commit` separately... which actually seems like the Right Thing. (Well, in bash; I don't know zsh enough to know semantics there).

Comment: I had that, then I looked more closely at the original and realized any "arguments" to the alias would be intended as part of the `-m` option (a time alone isn't much of a commit message). Maybe `-m "$(date +%T) $1" "${@:2}"` is what was intended?

Comment: Then perhaps you want `$*` rather than `$1`; throwing away all but the first argument doesn't seem likely to be right.